# GET http://localhost:5000/error 404 (Not Found)

Tags: node.js, reactjs

im trying to make a api call with node.js to datasciencetool kit with lat and long from react.js. Whenever user enters address i should get the data from the api call however im just getting 404 error in console. if i replace url with static values  like this http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/coordinates2statistics/37.769456%2c-122.429128?statistics=population_density then it works.

data.js

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

module.exports = (app) => {

  app.post('/search-data', (req, res) => {

    console.log(req);
    let lat = req.body.param.lat;//before: req.query.lat it's wrong

    let long = req.body.param.long;
    console.log(lat);



  const apiUrl = 'http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/coordinates2statistics' + lat + '%2c' + long+'?statistics=population_density';
        fetch(apiUrl).then(res=>res.json()).then(data=>{

            console.log(data)
               res.send({
                        data
                    });


})
        .catch(err => {
            res.redirect('/error');
        });


       })

}
```

home.js //react

```
handleSelect = address => {
    this.setState({
      address,
    });

    console.log(this.state.address);

    geocodeByAddress(address)
      .then(res => getLatLng(res[0]))
      .then(({ lat, lng }) => {
        this.setState({
          latitude: lat,
          longitude: lng,
          isGeocoding: false,
        });

        this.setState({ isLoaded: true });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ isGeocoding: false });
        console.log('error', error); // eslint-disable-line no-console
      });

    console.log(this.state.latitude);
    console.log(this.state.longitude);

     var param = {
      lat: this.state.latitude,
      long: this.state.longitude,
      temp: 1,
    };
    axios
      .post(`http://localhost:5000/search-data`, {
        param,
      })
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data);


    });

  };
```

latitude and longitude return correct values so im not sure whats going on. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you forget the **/** in coordinates2statistics/

```
 const apiUrl = 'http://www.datasciencetoolkit.org/coordinates2statistics/' + lat + '%2c' + long+'?statistics=population_density
```